# Removing sliver polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, slivers

I unioned 2 layers into 1 layer, and it created sliver polygons.

I used the elimination tool to merge them with neighboring polygons.

As as result, it merges all sliver polygons to only one polygon (selected in the picture).

What I need, is that, every sliver polygon to be added to its neighboring polygon.

How that could be achieved?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself.

After unioning the layers, the silver polygons were added as a single polygon.

Therefore I had to use the Explode Multi-part Feature tool from advanced editing toolbar, which separated the polygon into multiple single polygons.

Then the Elimination tool was able to add the polygons to neighboring polygons easily.

Answer (score 1):

If the sliver polygons share a common attribute value with the neightbouring polygons, you could try to use "Dissolve" from the Data Management toolbox.

But, it's strange that the union of two polygon layers generates that sliver polygons. The problem should be on the original layers. You could try to repair the geometries on both layers and use the "Integrate" tool to ensure no sliver polygons are created after the union.

Comment: Actually 2 of the layers were not of the same size. One was slightly smaller, thus leaving those sliver polygons(edges). Those sliver polygons mark the difference of two layers in my opinion. Elimination should be the tool just for these cases: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Eliminate%20(Data%20Management)