# Dissolved polygon shows 'ghost' of previous 'child' boundaries

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I dissolved the polygons specifically to get a unified outline without any interior boundaries showing.  Now I've got a partially broken interior line within the polygon.

This is for cartographic display reasons; I know that I can display the polygon without a boundary, but I'm already using that technique to display another layer in the map.

I used the dissolve tool in ArcMap 10 (ArcInfo) SP4.

**Why does this tool leave artifacts of previous polygon boundaries??**

[image: Polygon artifacts]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a sliver between the original polygons. You will have to edit those vertices out.
You could use the [eliminate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/removing-small-spaces-between-polygons) (arcinfo).
Also this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24361/removing-sliver-polygons-arcgis-10) has some direction
Also another direction to what you did would be the trace command [(resources.esri)](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/11/04/getting-the-most-out-of-editing-in-arcgis-10-tracing-features/)

Comment: That is to say they need to _exactly_ share that border?

Comment: yes, that is how dissolve works. I think there is a tolerance seting but from my old school experience you don't have much control over how the tol is applied.

Comment: Thanks, I inserted vertices on one of the polygons with snapping and everything went through the second time.